# Laravel 5 FTP Upload

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel Project that uses FTP Service, so I used this https://github.com/harishanchu/Laravel-FTP . However I can't make the upload to work. I have a proper connection and I was able to make a new directories to the remote server. Only the upload doesn't work. Am I doin wrong with the parameters?

```
$ftp_upload     = FTP::connection()->uploadFile($file_loc, $current_dir);
```

When I var_dump() my $file_loc

```
string 'C:\wamp\www\callrec\public\uploads\joene1212\01313313116_SoniaSantos482UK_2015-04-28-20-22-25.wav'
```

Which totally exists in the directory and my $current_dir in my remote directory is

```
string '/CallRecordingsUpload/joene1212'
```

Where $file_loc is the local source and $file_loc is the remote directory where it will be uploaded.

Comment: did u find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is making directories but not uploading the file, chances are your PHP file upload limits are set at the default 2MB.

Try adding the following lines to .htaccess

```
memory_limit = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```